# How to execute a NodeJS function in Pug

Tags: node.js, pug

I've got some node js code which is responsible for creating a function, that I want to execute in my .pug template.

```
let pages = [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Index"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "About"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Kontakt"
    },
];

function navigation(pages) {
    return pages;
}


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.write(navigation(pages));
    res.render("index");
});
```

How can I call for this function in the pug template or what is a better way to pass a function from node to jade?

Comment: @xMayank yes, kind of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using express.js with node.js,

in the node.js back end, write:

```js
function navigation() {
  let pages = [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: "Index"
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "About"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Kontakt"
    }
  ];
  return pages;
}

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index", { navigation: navigation });
});
```

In the pug template, write:

```
script !{navigation}
```

A demo: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/pass-javascript-functions-from-node-js-to-pug

Answer (score 0):

OK ffmaer between that answer and your demo you almost got me to where I needed to be... Now the problem is that i need to pass a variable to the script.

When I use the following code i get

> Uncaught ReferenceError: p is not defined

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title foobar
    script !{getProfile}
  body
    ul
      each p in profiles
        script.getProfile(p);
```

but if do

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title foobar
    script !{getProfile}
  body
    ul
      each p in profiles
        li=p
```

everything works perfectly.

Comment: I strongly suspect you're confusing client and server-side scripting here. Where are these profiles coming from? What exactly do you expect getProfile to do?